# Remove lines after match, until blank line occurs

Tags: bash, awk, pattern-matching

I have an ldif file, and am retrieving a matching line, plus those following until I reach a blank line. This works fine.

```
$ awk '/dn:\ cn=test/,/pattern|^$/' $file
dn: cn=test,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com
cn: John
sn: Smith
givenname: Test
mail: test@test.com
userpassword: password
uid: test
defaultgroup: cn=test,cn=test01,cn=groups,dc=test,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetorgperson
objectclass: user
objectclass: user2
```

What I'd like to know, is how can I then remove those lines from the file?

Comment: Sorry - for clarification. i'm looking to remove those lines from the original file, essentially removing the whole stanza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove those lines from the input file, you can negate the range using `!`, so only the other lines are printed:

```
awk '!(/dn:\ cn=test/,/pattern|^$/)' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
```

The output is redirected to a temporary file, then the original file is overwritten.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I hadn't thought of that approach. The only issue being is that I've got a large number - approx 500,000 accounts to iterate through. Is there anyway I can do in-place removal? The source file is almost 1Gb, and I don't want to be re-writing it each time.

Comment: Unfortunately, even methods that pretend to edit in-place are going to create a new file behind the scenes, so your options are limited.